# Why is gstreamer-rs deinterleave element showing src pad that isn't there?

Tags: rust, gstreamer, gstreamer-rs

I am trying to build a dynamic pipeline that includes a `deinterleave` element and am running into a curious issue. `ElementExt::foreach_pad` is showing two src pads `src_0` and `src_1`, yet a call to `request_pad_simple("src_%u")` returns `None`.

Here is the launch script I wish to implement:

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
    filesrc location=yo.mp3 \
    ! decodebin \
    ! audioconvert \
    ! deinterleave name=d \
    audiomixer name=mix \
    ! wavenc \
    ! filesink location=yo.wav \
    d.src_0 ! mix.sink_0 \
    d.src_1 ! mix.sink_1
```

It converts a 2-channel `mp3` file into a mono `wav` file.

Here is the Rust code that builds my pipeline:

```rust
    let pipeline = gst::Pipeline::default();
    let src = gst::ElementFactory::make("filesrc").property("location", "yo.mp3").build().unwrap();
    let decodebin = gst::ElementFactory::make("decodebin").build().unwrap();
    pipeline.add_many([&src, &decodebin]).unwrap();
    gst::Element::link_many([&src, &decodebin]).unwrap();

    let pipeline_weak = pipeline.downgrade();
    decodebin.connect_pad_added(move |_, src_pad| {
        let pipeline = pipeline_weak.upgrade().unwrap();
        let audioconvert = gst::ElementFactory::make("audioconvert").build().unwrap();
        let deinterleave = gst::ElementFactory::make("deinterleave").build().unwrap();

        pipeline.add_many([&audioconvert, &deinterleave]).unwrap();
        gst::Element::link_many([&audioconvert, &deinterleave]).unwrap();
        for e in &[&audioconvert, &deinterleave] {
            e.sync_state_with_parent().unwrap();
        }

        let audioconvert_sink = audioconvert.static_pad("sink").unwrap();
        src_pad.link(&audioconvert_sink).unwrap();

        let pipeline_weak = pipeline.downgrade();
        deinterleave.connect_no_more_pads(move |d| {
            let pipeline = pipeline_weak.upgrade().unwrap();
            let audiomixer = gst::ElementFactory::make("audiomixer").build().unwrap();
            let wavenc = gst::ElementFactory::make("wavenc").build().unwrap();
            let filesink = gst::ElementFactory::make("filesink").property("location", "yo.wav").build().unwrap();

            pipeline.add_many([&audiomixer, &wavenc, &filesink]).unwrap();
            gst::Element::link_many([&audiomixer, &wavenc, &filesink]).unwrap();
            for e in &[&audiomixer, &wavenc, &filesink] {
                e.sync_state_with_parent().unwrap();
            }

            // Here is the source of my confusion; this loop outputs three lines: "sink", "src_0",
            // and "src_1"...
            d.foreach_pad(|_, pad| {
                println!("deinterleave pad: {}", pad.name().as_str());
                true
            });
            // ...and yet my code panics here with "called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value"
            let deinterleave_src_0 = d.request_pad_simple("src_%u").unwrap();
            let mixer_sink_0 = audiomixer.request_pad_simple("sink_%u").unwrap();
            deinterleave_src_0.link(&mixer_sink_0).unwrap();

            let deinterleave_src_1 = d.request_pad_simple("src_%u").unwrap();
            let mixer_sink_1 = audiomixer.request_pad_simple("sink_%u").unwrap();
            deinterleave_src_1.link(&mixer_sink_1).unwrap();
        });
    });
```

What is wrong with this code? How should I correctly connect a `deinterleave` element's src pads to an `audiomixer` element's sink(s)?

**Update**
For those curious about this question, and (maybe) for more context...

After posting this question, I went back to throwing poop at ye olde wall and made this:

```rust
    let pipeline = gst::Pipeline::default();
    let src = gst::ElementFactory::make("filesrc").property("location", "yo.mp3").build().unwrap();
    let decodebin = gst::ElementFactory::make("decodebin").build().unwrap();
    pipeline.add_many([&src, &decodebin]).unwrap();
    gst::Element::link_many([&src, &decodebin]).unwrap();

    let pipeline_weak = pipeline.downgrade();
    decodebin.connect_pad_added(move |_, src_pad| {
        let pipeline = pipeline_weak.upgrade().unwrap();
        let audioconvert = gst::ElementFactory::make("audioconvert").build().unwrap();
        let deinterleave = gst::ElementFactory::make("deinterleave").build().unwrap();

        pipeline.add_many([&audioconvert, &deinterleave]).unwrap();
        gst::Element::link_many([&audioconvert, &deinterleave]).unwrap();
        for e in &[&audioconvert, &deinterleave] {
            e.sync_state_with_parent().unwrap();
        }

        let audiomixer = gst::ElementFactory::make("audiomixer").build().unwrap();
        let wavenc = gst::ElementFactory::make("wavenc").build().unwrap();
        let filesink = gst::ElementFactory::make("filesink").property("location", "yo.wav").build().unwrap();

        pipeline.add_many([&audiomixer, &wavenc, &filesink]).unwrap();
        gst::Element::link_many([&audiomixer, &wavenc, &filesink]).unwrap();
        for e in &[&audiomixer, &wavenc, &filesink] {
            e.set_state(State::Null).unwrap();
        }

        let audiomixer_weak = audiomixer.downgrade();
        deinterleave.connect_pad_added(move |_, src_pad| {
            let audiomixer = audiomixer_weak.upgrade().unwrap();
            let audiomixer_sink = audiomixer.request_pad_simple("sink_%u").unwrap();
            src_pad.link(&audiomixer_sink).unwrap();
        });

        let audioconvert_sink = audioconvert.static_pad("sink").unwrap();
        src_pad.link(&audioconvert_sink).unwrap();
    });
```

This doesn't get me any further toward understanding *why* I can't request a src pad from inside a `connect_no_more_pads` method, but it *does* create a pipeline that gives the same result as the `gst-launch` invocation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot request a pad from `deinterlave`. Deinterleave exposes as many pads as it makes sense depending on the input format. You connect them or you don't.

An `audiomixer` on the other hand can mix up to an arbitrary number of channels. Audiomixer does not know about how many input pads you want/need so you have to request them individually.

From `gst-inspect-1.0`:

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 deinterleave
..
  SRC template: 'src_%u'
    Availability: Sometimes
```

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 audiomixer
..
  SINK template: 'sink_%u'
    Availability: On request
```

Comment: Ah, I had seen that distinction in the gstreamer docs, but was unclear about its meaning. I was also confused about the meaning of "request" in `request_pad_simple` -- I thought it meant "Please provide a reference to a pad that already exists so I can work with it;" apparently it means "Please create a non-existent pad for me." This is helpful. Thank you.